# Can this code be refactored to a more functional programming style using hof/compose/currying/partial application/monads?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition, currying

I've just started learning about functional programming and I'm trying to put into practice what I've learned. I've got this code below and I just don't know where can I apply function composition, partial application in this function.

Any ideas how to refactor this using the functional techniques?

```
function compareCodes(validateFn, moreProcessingFn, doStuffOnCodeAFn, doStuffOnCodeBFn, doSomething1Fn, doSomething2Fn, codeA, codeB, param1, param2) {

    let result = null;
    if (validateFn(codeA, codeB)) {
        const isCodeAValid = doStuffOnCodeAFn(codeA);  // returns a boolean
        const isCodeBValid = doStuffOnCodeBFn(codeB);  // returns a boolean
        const isItAMatch = moreProcessingFn(isCodeAValid, isCodeBValid, codeA, codeB); // returns a boolean
        if (isItAMatch) {
            result = doSomething1Fn (param1, param2);
        } else {
            result = doSomething2Fn (param1, param2);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Paul Code Review does not review questions involving `doSomething` placeholders. Furthermore, even if it were an on-topic question for Code Review, "belongs on _some other site_" [would not constitute a valid closure reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260769/148099).

Comment: Why would you wrap the nested condition in a function in the first place? A higher order function with more than three arguments can be regularly refactored.

Comment: @ftor - Can you please show me how you regularly refactor a hof with more than 3 arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to get rid of all the helper variables. While the boolean intermediate variables ease understanding with their descriptive names, at least `result` is totally unnecessary.

```
function compareCodes(validateFn, moreProcessingFn, doStuffOnCodeAFn, doStuffOnCodeBFn, doSomething1Fn, doSomething2Fn, codeA, codeB, param1, param2) {
    return validateFn(codeA, codeB)
      ? (moreProcessingFn(doStuffOnCodeAFn(codeA), doStuffOnCodeBFn(codeB), codeA, codeB)
          ? doSomething1Fn
          : doSomething2Fn
        )(param1, param2)
      : null;
}
```

Next you could apply some currying (you could do it per parameter, but I think it's more useful in the blocks that will likely be used together):

```
function compareCodes(validateFn, moreProcessingFn, doStuffOnCodeAFn, doStuffOnCodeBFn, doSomething1Fn, doSomething2Fn) {
    return function(codeA, codeB) {
        return validateFn(codeA, codeB)
          ? moreProcessingFn(doStuffOnCodeAFn(codeA), doStuffOnCodeBFn(codeB), codeA, codeB)
              ? doSomething1Fn
              : doSomething2Fn
          : function(param1, param2) { return null; };
    };
}
```

But that's about it. While it would be possible to write your own combinators for the conditionals and the parallel feeding of multiple arguments into multiple functions, you will not gain anything in the process. There certainly are no standard combinators like composition that would help you out here.

It might be a different thing if you drop out of always supplying two things together (A and B, 1 and 2) but as distinct parameters. If you instead modify all of your functions to take tuples instead (here represented as arrays of length 2, given JavaScript's lack of a pair type), we can do something. First we convert from

```
function compareCodes(validateFn, moreProcessingFn, [doStuffOnCodeAFn, doStuffOnCodeBFn], [doSomething1Fn, doSomething2Fn], [codeA, codeB], [param1, param2]) {
    return validateFn([codeA, codeB])
      ? (moreProcessingFn([doStuffOnCodeAFn(codeA), doStuffOnCodeBFn(codeB)], [codeA, codeB])
          ? doSomething1Fn
          : doSomething2Fn
        )([param1, param2])
      : null;
}
```

to (I'm using ES6 syntax, notable arrow functions and destructuring)

```
const bimap = ([f, g]) => ([x, y]) => [f(x), g(y)];
const fst = ([x, _]) => x;
const snd = ([_, y]) => y;

function compareCodes(validate, moreProcessing, doStuff, doSomething, code, param) {
    return validate(code)
      ? (moreProcessing(bimap(doStuff)(code), code)
          ? fst
          : snd
        )(doSomething)(param)
      : null;
}
```

Now that is something we can indeed tackle with combinators:

```
const compose = f => g => x => f(g(x));
const bind = f => g => x => f(g(x), x);
const cond = pred => then => other => x => pred(x) ? then(x) : other(x);
const k = x => _ => x;


function compareCodes(validate, moreProcessing, doStuff, doSomething)
    return cond(validate,
                cond(bind(moreProcessing)(compose(bimap)(doStuff)),
                    fst(doSomething),
                    snd(doSomething)
                ),
                k(k(null))
           );
}
```

We could go further to a completely point-free definition of `compareCodes`, but honestly that's not worth it.

Comment: Really appreciate @Bergi for your answer. It's really helpful into making me thinking in functional.

Comment: I hope you don't mind asking me a further question about helper variables.
What if you have a helper variable and this helper variable is used multiple times in the function?

Let's say I have this:

`function matchCode(codeA, codeB) {
    let hashMapData = createMap(); // an expensive operation
    const arrA = createArrayFromCode(codeA, hashMapData);
    const arrB = createArrayFromCode(codeB, hashMapData);
    return (arrA.length > 0 && arrB.length > 0) ? compareArray(arrA, arrB) : true;
}`
how would you go about refactoring this scenario?

Comment: @Bergi nice usage of `bind`

Comment: @Darwin If you use it sequentially in two parameters, you can often use `bind` (from the function monad), see the above example with `code`. In your comment you are essentially doing things in parallel again so if you use `code` and `arr` tuples and execute things element-wise, you'd need only one `hasMapData`.

Comment: @ftor `>>=` is invaluable when programming pointfree functions in Haskell :-)